# Attribute Routing for querystring

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have below route URL:-

```
www.domanname.com/subroute/GetInfo?param1=somestring&param2=somestring
```

I have function in webapi as:-

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public object GetInfo(string param1,string param2)
    {}
}
```

To apply route:-

```
[RoutePrefix("subroute")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetInfo?param1={param1:string}&param2={param2:string}")]
    public object GetInfo(string param1,string param2)
    {}
}
```

But after applying above URL:-

```
www.domanname.com/subroute/GetInfo?param1=somestring&param2=somestring
```

It is not able to find that URL

How can I design this particular route?

Comment: Replace `[Route("GetInfo?param1={param1:string}&param2={param2:string}")]` with `[Route("GetInfo")]`. You don't need to put the query parameter into the route.

Comment: The route is determined by the IP address and Mask on the Network cards.  IP routing is determined by the Route with the more specific mask.  So a mask of 255.255.255.0 is used before a mask of 255.255.0.0.  So you would need to modify the mask of the network card.  Use cmd.exe > IPCONFIG /ALL to determine current settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the routes a bit as query string are not normally used in attribute routes. They tend to be used for inline route parameters.

```
[RoutePrefix("subroute")]
public class HomeController : ApiController {
    //Matches GET subroute/GetInfo?param1=somestring&param2=somestring
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetInfo")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInfo(string param1, string param2) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Also

> ### Enabling Attribute Routing
>
> To enable attribute routing, call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` during configuration. This extension method is
>   defined in the `System.Web.Http.HttpConfigurationExtensions` class.

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Other Web API configuration not shown.
        }
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: sorry, 404 with this :- No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Comment: @CSharper have you enabled attribute routing in WebApiConfig.cs?

Comment: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); is there in WebApiConfig

Comment: thanks this worked after making few changes, I was calling url in wrong way :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[RoutePrefix("subroute")]
public class HomeController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetInfo/{param1}/{param2}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInfo(string param1, string param2) {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Calling**

```
//Matches GET subroute/GetInfo/Hello/World
```

Comment: Just edited my answer, and please send the url, how you actually calling?

Comment: but my url is fixed and I need to adjust my route accordingly

Comment: Ok @CSharper but working with querystring in api/mvc is not good approach. if it is web form, then its ok. Thanks